# Save images in loop with different names

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem with saving cropped images in a loop. My code:

```
def run(self, image_file):
    print(image_file)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(image_file)
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            img = frame
            min_h = int(max(img.shape[0] / self.min_height_dec, self.min_height_thresh))
            min_w = int(max(img.shape[1] / self.min_width_dec, self.min_width_thresh))
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces = self.face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(min_h, min_w))

            images = []
            for i, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(faces):
                images.append(self.sub_image('%s/%s-%d.jpg' % (self.tgtdir, self.basename, i + 1), img, x, y, w, h))
            print('%d faces detected' % len(images))

            for (x, y, w, h) in faces: 
                self.draw_rect(img, x, y, w, h)
                # Fix in case nothing found in the image
            outfile = '%s/%s.jpg' % (self.tgtdir, self.basename)
            cv2.imwrite(outfile, img)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return images, outfile
```

I have a loop for every frame with cropping on faces. The problem is that for every cropped image and picture it gives the same name, and in the end I have faces only from the last frame. How should I fix this code to save all cropped faces and images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are saving each file with the same name. Hence you are overwriting previous saved images

```
outfile = '%s/%s.jpg' % (self.tgtdir, self.basename)
```

Change the line to this to add a random string in the name

```
outfile = '%s/%s.jpg' % (self.tgtdir, self.basename + str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

You will need to `import uuid` at the top of your file too

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `datetime` module to get the current time with milliseconds precision, which would avoid the name conflicts, to assign the name before saving the image as:

```
from datetime import datetime

outfile = '%s/%s.jpg' % (self.tgtdir, self.basename + str(datetime.now()))
cv2.imwrite(outfile, img)
```

You can also use other techniques such as `uuid4` to get unique random id for each frame, but since the name would be random it would cumbersome on some platforms to display them in sorted orders, So I think using timestamp in name would get your job done.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
i = 0

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    i = i +1
    ret, frame = cap.read()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
**cv2.imwrite("template {0}.jpg".format(i),gray)**


if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

--- Code by rohbhot

Comment: Works for me, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

i think this will helpful...

```
import cv2

vid = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
d = 0
ret, frame = vid.read()

while ret:
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    filename = "images/file_%d.jpg"%d
    cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
    d+=1
```

this will save every frame with different name.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.savefig('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/res_data/dimers/'+str(yname)+'_'+str(xname)+'_'+str(dimername), bbox_inches='tight' )
            
you can save as :                
      
/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/res_data/dimers/zeta_beta_GA.png
```