# Saving Images in a For Loop with Different Names Without Using a User Function (sckit - Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I am looking to save a set of processed images into a folder within my directory. There have been similar questions (e.g., [Save images in loop with different names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535290/save-images-in-loop-with-different-names)), however they either use user defined functions or rely on the images being part of a video that they decompose frame-by-frame and then save.

Using another question, I was looking to accomplish something similar ([OpenCV - Saving images to a particular folder of choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586429/opencv-saving-images-to-a-particular-folder-of-choice)), but within a loop structure

```
import cv2
import os

path = 'D:\Results'

for i in range(len(images))
     cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'waka.tif'), )
     cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But am unsure of what to put in place of the `waka` title the previous questioner gave the image.

Comment: Why don't you put a timestamp instead of waka if that is the question

Comment: Oh, I see what you are asking what to pass to opencv to write at the path location right? What does images contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put `'waka_{}.tif'.format(i)` this will save one image every time it goes through the loop and you will then have waka_1.tif, waka_2.tif, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
import cv2
import os

path = 'D:\Results'

for i in range(len(images))
     cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'waka_'+str(i)+'.tif'), )
     cv2.waitKey(0)
```